# trouble with React Table 7 unique key warning

Tags: reactjs, react-table-v7

I am using React Table 7 to build my tables, and the tables render but I'm getting a warning `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` I have included keys in the headerGroup map and the rows but am still getting the warning. There error seems to only be point to line 137, where i do have a key

```
<thead>
 {headerGroups.map((headerGroup, i) => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} key={headerGroup.id}> ...
```

and line 176 where I have:

```
<tr
                      key={row.id}
                      {...row.getRowProps()}
                      onClick={rowOnClick ? () => rowClickHandler(row.original) : () => ""}
                    >
```

Where am I missing a key?

TABLE

```
 <React.Fragment>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" responsive {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
              {headerGroups.map((headerGroup, i) => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} key={headerGroup.id}>
                  {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                    <th
                      className={`p-2 table-header ${headerColor ? "primary-" + headerColor : "primary-deq"}`}
                      {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                    >
                      <span {...column.getSortByToggleProps()}>
                        {column.render("Header")}
                        {column.isSorted ? (
                          column.isSortedDesc ? (
                            <FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-3" icon={faArrowDown} />
                          ) : (
                            <FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-3" icon={faArrowUp} />
                          )
                        ) : (
                          ""
                        )}
                      </span>
                      <div {...column.getResizerProps()} className="resizer" />
                      {column.canResize && (
                        <div
                          {...column.getResizerProps()}
                          className={`resizer ${column.isResizing ? "isResizing" : ""}`}
                        />
                      )}
                      <div>{column.canFilter ? column.render("Filter") : null}</div>
                    </th>
                  ))}
                </tr>
              ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
              {page.map((row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <tr
                      key={row.id}
                      {...row.getRowProps()}
                      onClick={rowOnClick ? () => rowClickHandler(row.original) : () => ""}
                    >
                      {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                        return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
                      })}
                    </tr>
                    {row.isExpanded ? (
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <span className="subTable">{renderRowSubComponent({ row })}</span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ) : null}
                  </React.Fragment>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
          {showPagination ? (
            <Row className="mt-2 text-center">
              <Col>
                <Button
                  className="mr-2"
                  size="sm"
                  variant="secondary"
                  onClick={() => gotoPage(0)}
                  disabled={!canPreviousPage}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDoubleLeft} />
                </Button>
                <Button
                  className="mr-2"
                  size="sm"
                  variant="secondary"
                  onClick={() => previousPage()}
                  disabled={!canPreviousPage}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleLeft} />
                </Button>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <span>
                  Page{" "}
                  <strong>
                    {pageIndex + 1} of {pageOptions.length}
                  </strong>{" "}
                </span>
                <span>
                  | Go to page:{" "}
                  <InputGroup size="sm" style={{ width: "20%", display: "inline-flex" }}>
                    <FormControl
                      type="number"
                      defaultValue={pageIndex + 1}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        const page = e.target.value ? Number(e.target.value) - 1 : 0;
                        gotoPage(page);
                      }}
                    />
                  </InputGroup>
                </span>{" "}
                <InputGroup size="sm" style={{ width: "30%", display: "inline-flex" }}>
                  <FormControl
                    size="sm"
                    as="select"
                    value={pageSize}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setPageSize(Number(e.target.value));
                    }}
                  >
                    {[5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50].map((pageSize) => (
                      <option key={pageSize} value={pageSize}>
                        Show {pageSize}
                      </option>
                    ))}
                  </FormControl>
                </InputGroup>
              </Col>
              <Col>
                <Button
                  className="mr-2"
                  size="sm"
                  variant="secondary"
                  onClick={() => nextPage()}
                  disabled={!canNextPage}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleRight} />{" "}
                </Button>
                <Button
                  className="mr-2"
                  size="sm"
                  variant="secondary"
                  onClick={() => gotoPage(pageCount - 1)}
                  disabled={!canNextPage}
                >
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDoubleRight} />
                </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </React.Fragment>
```

ERROR:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `DtsReactTable`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
tr
DtsReactTable@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:11780:23
div
./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Col.js/Col<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:36550:18
div
./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Row.js/Row<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:40631:18
EnforcementActionsTable@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4237:11
div
./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Col.js/Col<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:36550:18
div
./node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Row.js/Row<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:40631:18
IncidentSummaryPage@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1056:5
ConnectFunction@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:75747:75
Route@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:78589:29
Switch@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:78791:29
div
div
Router@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:78224:30
ConnectedRouter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:17909:22
ConnectedRouterWithContext@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:18014:19
ConnectFunction@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:75747:75
Provider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:75460:15
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:176:1 
    in DtsReactTable (at EnforcementActionsTable.js:149)
    in EnforcementActionsTable (at IncidentSummaryPage.js:187)
    in IncidentSummaryPage (created by Connect(IncidentSummaryPage))
    in Connect(IncidentSummaryPage) (at App.js:98)
    in Router.Consumer (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:95)
    in App (at src/​index.js:10) index.js:1
    e index.js:1
    r backend.js:6
    React 5
    DtsReactTable DtsReactTable.js:136
    React 9
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:646
    React 4
    Redux 4
    e 1040:1
    immutableStateInvariantMiddleware Immutable
    createThunkMiddleware Redux
    routerMiddleware middleware.js:22
    Redux 4
    routerMiddleware middleware.js:22
    dispatch 1040:1
    bindActionCreator Redux
    componentDidMount IncidentSummaryPage.js:50
    React 6
    unstable_runWithPriority scheduler.development.js:646
    React 9
    js index.js:10
    js main.chunk.js:13289
    Webpack 7
```

Comment: If you are seeing this warning even after providing "keys", the reason could be that one or more key values are `undefined`. So, you should check that none of those are `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have keys in few place in this code.. e.g

```js
{ headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
    <th
        className={`p-2 table-header ${headerColor ? "primary-" + headerColor : "primary-deq"}`
        {...column.getHeaderProps()}
```

Another problem may be that your keys are not unique.
When you use **map** you can use the second parameter which is the iteration number, this will guarantee that your keys will be unique. E.g

```js
{headerGroups.map((headerGroup, i) => ( <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()} key={i}> ... 

// i instead of headerGroup.id is unique
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `key` props in each mapping. for e.g

```
{headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => {
  const { key, ...restHeaderProps } = headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps();

  return (
    <tr key={key} {...restHeaderProps}>
      {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => {
        const { key, ...restColumnProps } = column.getHeaderProps();

        return (
          <th key={key} {...restColumnProps}>
            {column.render("Header")}
          </th>
        );
      })}
    </tr>
  );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `React table` handle its own key on each child you map. So if you add your own, you'll end up with another error saying that your key will be override.
2. To solve it you can add this lines to disable eslint since react table handle the key internaly:

```
    eslint-disable-next-line eslint-comments/disable-enable-pair
    eslint-disable react/jsx-key
```

3. Check this [discussion](https://github.com/TanStack/table/discussions/2647). There is a workaround that will solve the problem. Basically they distracture react-table methods and use the key like:

```
{row.cells.map((cell) => {
  const { key, ...restCellProps } = cell.getCellProps();
  return (
   <div key={key} {...restCellProps}>
     {cell.render('Cell')}
   </div>
 );
})}
```